# How to save files on the sql server database using struts2

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, struts2

I am new bee into struts2.

As I have a reqirement that stores a file into the sql server database.And retrive the same.

Please provide me a sample code or an example so that i can proceed for the same

I am using struts2.x and backend server as mysql server 2008.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you want to upload the file and than want to save it or you have to fetch it from somewhere and than save it..?

Comment: i want to upload the file into database

Comment: please clarify what you mean by upload? just describe what all you want to do..? generaly upload means uploading the file from a client machine to server like what we do in gmail etc.your term *upload to database* is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can found solutions on below links:

```
it will show you:

1. create database
2. write files
3. retrieve files
```

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx

http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/08/31/storing-and-retrieving-docpdfxls-files-in-sql-server/